# What is the exact difference between these two groups of statements?

Tags: java, collections

```
Set<Type> union = new HashSet<Type>(s1);
```

And

```
Set<Type> union = new HashSet<Type>();
Set<Type> s1 = new HashSet<Type>();
union.addAll(s1);
```

Comment: Sorry ,I edited my question:)

Comment: plz add the "collection" tag to this question...

Comment: @Peter Kofler: Good suggestion! 'collections' tag has been added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `Set` `s1` contains the same contents in the first and second examples, the end results should come out to be the same.

(However, the second example will not compile because a `Set` is an interface rather than a concrete class.)

One advantage of using the [`HashSet(Collection)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet(java.util.Collection)) constructor is that it will have an initial capacity that is enough to hold the `Collection` (in this case, the `Set` `s1`) that is passed into the constructor:

> Constructs a new set containing the
>   elements in the specified collection.
>   The `HashMap` is created with default
>   load factor (0.75) and an initial
>   capacity sufficient to contain the
>   elements in the specified collection.

However, using the [`HashSet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet()) constructor, the initial size is 16, so if the `Set` that was added via the [`Collection.addAll`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) is larger than 16, there would have to be a resizing of the data structure:

> Constructs a new, empty set; the
>   backing `HashMap` instance has default
>   initial capacity (16) and load factor
>   (0.75).

Therefore, using the [`HashSet(Collection)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet(java.util.Collection)) constructor to create the `HashSet` would probably be a better option in terms of performance and efficiency.

However, from the standpoint of readability of the code, the variable name `union` seems to imply that the newly created `Set` is an union of another `Set`, so probably the one using the `addAll` method would be more understandable code.

If the idea is just to make a new `Set` from an existing one, then the newly created `Set` should probably be named differently, such as `newSet`, `copyOfS1` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 7):

The **first will be more efficient** because the second `Set` will be created with the correct amount of space in the backing data structure where in the second piece of code, the `Set` will have to resize to make room for the new elements.

**As far as end results go, they are the same.**

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.  Both will create a new set that contains all of the elements in the set s1.

Of course, your second code sample won't even compile, since you can't directly instantiate the `Set` interface, but I'm assuming that you meant to say `new HashSet` instead of `new Set`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little difference, in that the new HashSet(s1) will make sure beforehand that all elements will fit, and no rehashing is needed.